# android permission exception

Tags: android, exception, permissions

I am having following error in android programming 
"Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" #android #permission

Comment: Did you tried to add this permission?

Comment: Yes i tried android:permission="INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" in manifest class but still same error

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL` permission, as it is signature level permission and no app will not be able to use it until and unless it has the same signature as the system.

> **signature**
>
> A permission that the system grants only if the requesting application
> is signed with the same certificate as the application that declared
> the permission. If the certificates match, the system automatically
> grants the permission without notifying the user or asking for the
> user's explicit approval.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel